# Has Burdges and De Feo's concept of Delayed Encryption ever been implemented?

Tags: public-key, implementation, isogeny, timed-release

In mid 2020 Jeffrey Burdges and Luca De Feo published [a paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/638.pdf) proposing a trapdoor-less time-lock puzzle called Delay Encryption. Has a prototype of this ever been made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is PoC code for the De Feo-Masson-Petit-Sanso VDF here: https://github.com/isogenies-vdf/isogenies-vdf-sage. It's easily adapted to Delay Encryption.